# url redirect is working but rewriting is showing blank page

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I have created a rule to rewrite this 
"http://192.111.111.111:8020/1B3KC46K48N6228671/20120524/1B3KC46K48N62286711_l1.jpg"

to

"http://192.111.111.111:8020/1B3KC46K48N62286711_l1.jpg?vin=1B3KC46K48N6228671&dt=20120524"

Rule is :

```
 <rule name="Redirect VIN">
      <match url="^(\w*)/(\d*)/(\w*.jpg)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:3}?vin={R:1}&amp;dt={R:2}" />
 </rule>
```

When applying the above rule as **"Redirect" its working absolutely fine**.
But when applying as **"Rewrite" its not working and showing a blank page.**

Any suggestion is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest. It's untested as I don't have access to a test machine at the moment:

```
<rule name="Redirect VIN">
     <match url="^(\w+)/(\d+)/(\w+\.jpg)$" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:3}?vin={UrlEncode:{R:1}}&amp;dt={UrlEncode:{R:2}}" />
</rule>
```

I've replaced your `\w*` and `\d*` with `\w+` and `\d+` to make it require at least a single character (minor thing). I've also changes `.jpg` to `\.jpg` to make it match the dot literally, otherwise the dot will be interpret as a regular expression character which means match any character.

Your main problem I think is that the rewrite URL should start with a `/`. Furthermore I've added the `{UrlEncode{...}}` to properly encode the parameters (not an issue with your example, but just in case). I think this should work, although, as I said, I can't test it.